# Python library to retrieve face pose from 68 landmark points

Tags: python, pose-estimation

Can anyone point me in the direction of a library that can estimate face pose from 68 landmark points in Python?

To be more specific, many such libraries exist. However, they usually start from an image. I want to skip the landmark detection because I already have it. I just want to feed the 68-point landmarks to a function and retrieve the rotation and translation of the face.

If I wasn't a complete Python newbie, I may be able tp extract the relevant bits and pieces from existing libraries but I am finding this hard to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This library seems to get your job done
https://github.com/yinguobing/head-pose-estimation

It seems to work in 3 steps,

1. Face Detection
2. Landmark Detection
3. Pose Estimation. After getting 68 facial landmarks, the pose could be calculated by a mutual PnP algorithm.

So, you should look through the codebase for this `mutual PnP algorithm` that is taking the 68 landmarks as an input.

[Looks like all the code regarding pose estimation that you will need is inside this file!](https://github.com/yinguobing/head-pose-estimation/blob/master/pose_estimator.py)

To briefly summarize the whole file of pose estimation code for you

- the `PoseEstimator` class contains all the relevant functions
- the `__init__` function is establishing `self.model_points` as the nose tip, chin, mouth coordinates. Its also handling camera internals, rotation and translation vectors. All of these are essential inputs to the PnP algorithm that is doing pose estimation
- `self._get_full_model_points()` is reading the landmark points from a file and storing it in `self.model_points_68`
- this class has the important function called `solve_pose_by_68_points` which is doing what you need. It is expecting an input of your landmarks.
- this `solve_pose_by_68_points()` function is used [inside this file](https://github.com/yinguobing/head-pose-estimation/blob/981cac645ea2618d25325870c95e62a6f0595ef4/estimate_head_pose.py#L128)
- the input to that function is a variable called `marks`

You need to figure out a way to feed your own landmark points into this `solve_pose_by_68_points` function, using the `marks` variable as a guide.

Or, just recreate the code from the `pose_estimator.py` file and the `solve_pose_by_68_points` function within it.

Side note - that function is simply calling `cv2.solvePnP`, openCVs implementation of the PnP algorithm I'm guessing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your pointers! It does looklike the solution is in this file. I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: I made some progress but there are choke points. When I call solve_pose_by_68_points(), I need to supply an OpenCV Mat object. What I have is a 2-dimension array. 

Currently, I'm using this code to convert my points array to a Numpy array which, from what I read elsewhere, is supposed to be the same as a Mat object in Python: 

numpy.array(points, np.float32)  

I have no clue if this is the proper way. I tried using the rotation data and the numbers are so small that I can't notice an actual pose change...

Comment: share your code somewhere, help me run it. give me your points array, and give me the solve_pose_by_68_points() function

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I made a gist where I put what I have so far. I do get numbers at the end but I do not think they are right... I'm not sure how to create a cv.Mat from an array. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/djipco/30d0108cc19b04fd8acd35881ff7defc